# Неверные данные в ответ на запрос (JSON, Retrofit, Java)

Tags: java, json, retrofit

Имею JSON:

```
{"response":{"count":30,"items":[{"id":31,"from_id":-116125443,"owner_id":-116125443,"date":1503404720,"marked_as_ads":0,"post_type":"post","text":"Еще одно подтверждение, как здорово заходят хиты даже через 15 лет. Немцы Reamonn в начале 2000-х сделали прорыв со своей меланхоличной \"Supergirl\". В 2017 году их успеть решили повторить Anna Nackab.","signer_id":276417933,"can_delete":1,"can_pin":1,"attachments":[{"type":"audio","audio":{"artist":"Программа \"Сэмпл один на Всех!\"","id":456241280,"owner_id":2000147926,"title":"Reamon vs. Anna Naclab","duration":25,"url":"https:\/\/vk.com\/mp3\/audio_api_unavailable.mp3","date":1503404721,"genre_id":1001}}],"post_source":{"type":"vk"},"comments":{"count":2,"can_post":1},"likes":{"count":5,"user_likes":1,"can_like":0,"can_publish":1},"reposts":{"count":1,"user_reposted":1}},{"id":30,"from_id":-116125443,"owner_id":-116125443,"date":1480571513,"marked_as_ads":0,"post_type":"post","text":"В 1991 году песня Марка Коэна \"Walking in Memphis\" появилась в эфирах радиостанций. За все время своего существования песня \"обросла\" каверами и ремиксами, использовалась в качестве саундтреков к фильмам. И по сей день припев песни является самым узнаваемым! Кстати, и по сей день это один из успешных синглов США и Великобритании.","can_delete":1,"can_pin":1,"attachments":[{"type":"audio","audio":{"artist":"Программа \"Сэмпл один на Всех!\"","id":456240538,"owner_id":2000129726,"title":"DJ Smash vs. Marc Cohn","duration":25,"url":"https:\/\/vk.com\/mp3\/audio_api_unavailable.mp3","date":1480571513,"genre_id":18}}],"post_source":{"type":"vk"},"comments":{"count":0,"can_post":1},"likes":{"count":5,"user_likes":1,"can_like":0,"can_publish":1},"reposts":{"count":1,"user_reposted":1}},{"id":29,"from_id":-116125443,"owner_id":-116125443,"date":1480338116,"marked_as_ads":0,"post_type":"post","text":"В 2000-х хит от группы \"Руки Вверх\" \"Песенка №5\" зазвучала на европейских танцполах в англоязычном варианте. Вот это, действительно оказалось приятным. Русскоязычная песня стала основой для многих кавер-версий и ремиксов от Атлантики до Тихого океана! Как это произошло - в нашей программе!","can_delete":1,"can_pin":1,"attachments":[{"type":"audio","audio":{"artist":"Программа \"Сэмпл один на Всех!\"","id":456240399,"owner_id":2000124826,"title":"Руки Вверх vs. ATC","duration":25,"url":"","date":1480338116,"genre_id":18,"no_search":1,"content_restricted":1}}],"post_source":{"type":"vk"},"comments":{"count":0,"can_post":1},"likes":{"count":7,"user_likes":1,"can_like":0,"can_publish":1},"reposts":{"count":1,"user_reposted":1}},{"id":28,"from_id":-116125443,"owner_id":-116125443,"date":1480337719,"marked_as_ads":0,"post_type":"post","text":"Музыка преображает человека. Напевая любимый мотив, Вы преображаете все вокруг. А припев современной песни так и просится запомнится... А если мотив песни Вы можете вспомнить через несколько лет, то главная задача автора решена - Вы стали его поклонником . Как изменялась одна популярная песня на протяжении нескольких лет. Добро пожаловать в мир программы.","can_delete":1,"can_pin":1,"attachments":[{"type":"audio","audio":{"artist":"Программа \"Сэмпл один на Всех!\"","id":456240300,"owner_id":2000124943,"title":"Frida Gold vs. Gala","duration":25,"url":"https:\/\/vk.com\/mp3\/audio_api_unavailable.mp3","date":1480337719,"genre_id":18}}],"post_source":{"type":"vk"},"comments":{"count":0,"can_post":1},"likes":{"count":4,"user_likes":1,"can_like":0,"can_publish":1},"reposts":{"count":1,"user_reposted":1}},{"id":27,"from_id":-116125443,"owner_id":-116125443,"date":1467535791,"marked_as_ads":0,"post_type":"post","text":"Этой истории уже более 10-ти лет. Для современной музыкальной истории не такой большой срок, но тем не менее, изменения очевидны.  DJ David Guetta еще раз подтвердил свое умение делать хорошие хиты, пусть и на старом материале. Об этом в нашей программе.","can_delete":1,"can_pin":1,"attachments":[{"type":"audio","audio":{"artist":"Программа \"Сэмпл Один на Всех!\"","id":456239491,"owner_id":2000338373,"title":"David Guetta vs. Alice Deejay","duration":25,"url":"https:\/\/vk.com\/mp3\/audio_api_unavailable.mp3","date":1467535791,"genre_id":18}}],"post_source":{"type":"vk"},"comments":{"count":0,"can_post":1},"likes":{"count":6,"user_likes":1,"can_like":0,"can_publish":1},"reposts":{"count":1,"user_reposted":1}}]}}
```

Делаю запрос:

```
@GET("/method/wall.get?")
    Call<WallInfo> getresponse (@Query("owner_id=") String OWNER_ID, @Query("offset") String OFFSET, @Query("count") String COUNT, @Query("v") String version,@Query("access_token") String access_token);
```

Достаю данные:

```
private void getresponse() throws IOException {
        Retrofit retrofit = NetworkClient.getRetrofitClient();
        WallInterface wallInterface = retrofit.create(WallInterface.class);
        Call<WallInfo> callwall = wallInterface.getresponse("-116125443", "0", "5", "5.52", "здесь пишу токен - все норм");
        callwall.enqueue(new Callback<WallInfo>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, Response wallresponse) {

                WallInfo wallInfo = (WallInfo) wallresponse.body();
                final by.dream.vk_groups.Response response = wallInfo.getResponse();
                final List<Item> items = response.getItems();
                final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(items.get(1).getText());
                textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
                textView.setText(sb);
                System.out.println("Text: "+sb.toString());
}
```

По итогу мне выводится ответ, но откуда он, я вообще не понимаю.... Т.е. мне надо забрать информацию из поля "text" каждого item. А мне прилетает что-то...

На всякий случай:

WallInfo:

```
public class WallInfo {

    @SerializedName("response")
    @Expose
    private Response response;

    public Response getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public void setResponse(Response response) {
        this.response = response;
    }

}
```

Response:

```
public class Response {

    @SerializedName("count")
    @Expose
    private Integer count;
    @SerializedName("items")
    @Expose
    private List<Item> items = null;

    public Integer getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(Integer count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

}
```

Item:

```
public class Item {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("from_id")
    @Expose
    private Integer fromId;
    @SerializedName("owner_id")
    @Expose
    private Integer ownerId;
    @SerializedName("date")
    @Expose
    private Integer date;
    @SerializedName("marked_as_ads")
    @Expose
    private Integer markedAsAds;
    @SerializedName("post_type")
    @Expose
    private String postType;
    @SerializedName("text")
    @Expose
    private String text;
    @SerializedName("signer_id")
    @Expose
    private Integer signerId;
    @SerializedName("can_delete")
    @Expose
    private Integer canDelete;
    @SerializedName("can_pin")
    @Expose
    private Integer canPin;
    @SerializedName("attachments")
    @Expose
    private List<Attachment> attachments = null;
    @SerializedName("post_source")
    @Expose
    private PostSource postSource;
    @SerializedName("comments")
    @Expose
    private Comments comments;
    @SerializedName("likes")
    @Expose
    private Likes likes;
    @SerializedName("reposts")
    @Expose
    private Reposts reposts;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getFromId() {
        return fromId;
    }

    public void setFromId(Integer fromId) {
        this.fromId = fromId;
    }

    public Integer getOwnerId() {
        return ownerId;
    }

    public void setOwnerId(Integer ownerId) {
        this.ownerId = ownerId;
    }

    public Integer getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Integer date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Integer getMarkedAsAds() {
        return markedAsAds;
    }

    public void setMarkedAsAds(Integer markedAsAds) {
        this.markedAsAds = markedAsAds;
    }

    public String getPostType() {
        return postType;
    }

    public void setPostType(String postType) {
        this.postType = postType;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public Integer getSignerId() {
        return signerId;
    }

    public void setSignerId(Integer signerId) {
        this.signerId = signerId;
    }

    public Integer getCanDelete() {
        return canDelete;
    }

    public void setCanDelete(Integer canDelete) {
        this.canDelete = canDelete;
    }

    public Integer getCanPin() {
        return canPin;
    }

    public void setCanPin(Integer canPin) {
        this.canPin = canPin;
    }

    public List<Attachment> getAttachments() {
        return attachments;
    }

    public void setAttachments(List<Attachment> attachments) {
        this.attachments = attachments;
    }

    public PostSource getPostSource() {
        return postSource;
    }

    public void setPostSource(PostSource postSource) {
        this.postSource = postSource;
    }

    public Comments getComments() {
        return comments;
    }

    public void setComments(Comments comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }

    public Likes getLikes() {
        return likes;
    }

    public void setLikes(Likes likes) {
        this.likes = likes;
    }

    public Reposts getReposts() {
        return reposts;
    }

    public void setReposts(Reposts reposts) {
        this.reposts = reposts;
    }

}
```

Comment: Не ясно есть ли у вас проблема, а если есть - то в чём она заключается. Возможно, вам надо `?` из запроса удалить?

Comment: Понятно. Сейчас сформирую другой вопрос. Наверное не полностью сформулировал.

Answer (score 0):

Переделал функцию с проверкой в консоли:

```
private void getresponse() throws IOException {
        Retrofit retrofit = NetworkClient.getRetrofitClient();
        WallInterface wallInterface = retrofit.create(WallInterface.class);
        Call<String> call = wallInterface.getresponse("-116125443", "0", "5", "5.52", "key");
        call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    if (response.body() !=null){
                        System.out.println("onSuccess - " +response.body());
                        //textView.setText(response.body());

                        try {
                            JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) new JSONObject(response.body()).get("response");
                            JSONArray items = (JSONArray) obj.get("items");

                            for (int i=0; i < items.length(); i++){
                                JSONObject item = (JSONObject) items.get(i);
                                String item_text = (String) item.get("text");
                                System.out.println("Value of field" + Integer.toString(i+1) + " is -> " + item_text);
                                textitems[i] = item_text;
                                //textView.setText(item_text);
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        //textView.setText(jsonresponse);



                    } else {
                        System.out.println("not Success");
                    }
                }
            }
```